# Html to pdf convert using jsPDF with html2canvas taking too much time to convert and download

Tags: javascript, typescript, jspdf, html2canvas

I tried to convert html to pdf convert and download with below this code. its working fine with proper convert HTML div to pdf convert and download, But for converting its taking too long time and download the pdf.

````
public convetToPDF() {
        var data = document.getElementById('contentToConvert');
        html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
            // Few necessary setting options
            var imgWidth = 208;
            var pageHeight = 295;
            var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
            var heightLeft = imgHeight;

            const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
            let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF
            var position = 0;
            pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)
            pdf.save('new-file.pdf'); // Generated PDF
        });
    }```
````

Comment: I'm also hitting this problem, PDF generation works but are there any best practices for making it performant?

Comment: before we leap into jsPDF would love to know if there is a solution for this ~ any thoughts on solutions / best practice?

Comment: did you find anything? to make it works fast? please advise